# API em .NET Core - api não encontra string de conexão do appsettings.json

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, connectionstring

Fiz todo o desenvolvimento em uma maquina windows mas depois de quase uma semana consegui fazer o deploy em uma maquina ubuntu 18.04 e acertar as configuração para acessar via https.

Mas agora me deparei com o seguinte erro quando preciso conectar com o banco.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
>   'connectionString')

Antes das alterações relacionadas ao servidor e ssl a string de conexao estava vindo com o valor mas agora ela vem nula

Meu Program.cs

```
public class Program ( a parte com mais mudanças para o deploy)
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseUrls("https://*:5001;http://*:5000", "http://*:80")
        .UseKestrel(options =>
              {
                  options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
                  {
                      listenOptions.UseHttps("chave.pfx", "senha");
                  });
              })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

No appsettings.json eu crio a string

```
     {
      "DbContextSettings": {
        "ConnectionString": "Host=host;Port=port;Pooling=true;Database=Banco;User Id=postgres;Password=******;"
      },
    }
```

No Startup.cs eu tento recuperar a string mas aqui ele não esta pegando a conexao lá do appsettings

```
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
         ...
         var connectionString = Configuration["DbContextSettings:ConnectionString"];
         services.AddDbContext<APIMeuContexto>(opts => opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
         ...
       }
```

Gostaria de entender o por que o appsettings não está mais sendo visto pelo startup (visto que antes de convigurar a api para deploy funcionava) e como arrumar isso.
Imagino que agora ele possa estar procurando o appsettings.json em outro lugar. Mas não sei como descobrir isso.

Comment: A pergunta foi marcada como duplicada mas não entendi a relação entre as duas perguntas.
A outra pergunta nao me ajudou em nada.
O que acontece aqui é que meu Startup não encontra a connectionstring no appsettings.json sendo que o nome está certo, logo, meu Startup.cs não esta vendo o appsetting.json.
Como falei, antes das configuraçoes feitas para o deploy estava funcionando.

Comment: Honestamente também não entendi a razão... Mas o seu problema é que o arquivo appsettings não está no diretório da aplicação. Para confirmar isso (e geralmente é o desejável) altere a linha do `AddJsonFile` para `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`. Dessa forma será mandatório ter um arquivo de configuração appsettings.json. Há algumas alternativas, mas essa seria a forma mais fácil de confirmar e posteriormente corrigir.

Comment: @tvdias Mas então, eu to usando assim mesmo .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
Lá no Startup. Tenho que colocar o caminho inteiro?

Comment: Não, o problema é que o arquivo não deve estar presente e a aplicação não retorna erro por conta do `optional: true`.

Comment: Remover o `optional: true` seria o 1o passo para garantir que sempre há o arquivo de configuração.

Comment: @tvdias
Acabei de descobrir o problema.
Eu tinha criado um contrutor que recebia `IHostingEnvironment env` sem perceber que eu já tinha o que recebia `IConfiguration configuration` e era lá que eu tava colocando e ele não chegava a ler o comando de adicionar o json.
Tentei colocar no que já tinha mas acabei tendo outro erro.No final dei mais uma pesquisada e encontrei a opção de colocar no **Program.cs**

Comment: Só queria entender por que minhas sinalizações são ignoradas.
A pergunta nao tem relação alguma com a pergunta colocada como motivo para o fechamento.
E ainda ganhei um voto contra.
Só quero alguem me envie uma pergunta realmente igual.
Ou aponte o real problema da minha pergunta.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Essas configurações variam de acordo com a versão do framework e, se não me engano, tem versões que nem é necessário especificar o arquivo de configuração (usando o DefaultWebHostBuilder). A classe startup idem, há algumas particularidades dependendo da versão.